# Policy/Polictics around Login Rate-Limits

Tags: java, authentication, webserver, rate-limiting

When working with login rate limits, would you consider the requests you did during the rate limit as a part of the rate limit calculation, or would you only consider only failed login attemts in the calculation?

**I save these log entries:**
I save the failed logins, both when you try with the wrong password ("**login_without_correct_password**"), or when you try with a non-existing username ("**login_without_existing_username**").
I also save the attempted login when you're currently ratelimited ("**login_during_rate_limit**")
And the successful logins ("**login_with_correct_password**")

I grab the last 5 login attempts, and if it contains no successful login, I return a ratelimit error (As long as the 5th positions entry-time is within 10 minutes).
However, I would like to know your thoughts about the "10 minutes of login attempts". Should I only fetch failed logins to this list, or should I also fetch ratelimited logins?
The 2 scenarios:

1. Skipping ratelimit requests would make the user able to login after exactly 10 minutes from the point where you got ratelimited ("**login_with_correct_password**", "**login_without_correct_password**", "**login_without_existing_username**")
2. Including ratelimit requests would make the user able to login after the 5th entry in the list has exceeded 10 minutes ("**login_with_correct_password**", "**login_without_correct_password**", "**login_without_existing_username**", "**login_during_rate_limit**")

   ```
    public boolean checkRateLimit(String ipAddress) {
    ArrayList<Log> lastFiveLoginAttempts = logService.getLogsByRequestIdsAndIpAddress(new String[]{"login_with_correct_password", "login_without_correct_password", "login_without_existing_username", "login_during_rate_limit"}, ipAddress, 5);

    boolean rateLimited = false;
    if (lastFiveLoginAttempts.size() > 0) {
        Optional<Log> lastFiveEntriesContainsASuccessfulLogin = lastFiveLoginAttempts.stream().filter(l -> l.getRequestId().equalsIgnoreCase("login_with_correct_password")).findFirst();
        if(lastFiveEntriesContainsASuccessfulLogin.isEmpty() && lastFiveLoginAttempts.size() == 5) {
            Log lastLog = lastFiveLoginAttempts.get(lastFiveLoginAttempts.size() - 1);
            Instant lastLogTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(lastLog.getTime().getTime());
            Instant tenMinutesAgo = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()).minus(Duration.ofMinutes(10));
            rateLimited = lastLogTime.isAfter(tenMinutesAgo);
        }
    }
    return rateLimited;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the last 5 attempts (including the successful and failures) for rate limiting calculation.

The rate limiting is an orthogonal concept for any microservice architecture. You define global criteria for all the services to throttle the requesters. If you mix the business logic like successful logins/ failed logins, it will be tough for the rate limiter to scale. You essentially would need to write a custom rate limiter for every service.

Also, rate-limiting services are now gets coupled with the logic system. It changes if you change the rate-limiting limit or business logic of login. Thus violating the single responsibility principle of design.

Moreover, from the login service point of view, the number of failed attempts probably means you need to raise some security vulnerability exceptions to the client who is calling to safeguard the client from fraudulent activities. So you probably should see the rate limiting as a way to stop the client to make unnecessary calls and some fraud detection engine to detect the failed logins.

Maybe something like

if n login requests (success/failure) within t mins as rate limit logic

M failed logins withing  T (should be bigger than t) caused fraud detection engine to activate and stop the client to login.